# Must FCC-certified modules be labelled with the correct FCC ID?

Tags: bluetooth, radio, wifi, fcc, regulations

The manufacturer of this radio module I bought claims that it's FCC certified, but  there's no FCC ID on it (though there is the FCC logo). If the final product is to be FCC tested, would it then be tested as an intentional radiator since there's no FCC ID on the radio module (rendering the certification invalid)? AFAIK, that costs a lot more than an unintentional radiator test.

Their website has the FCC ID - could I just print it on a sticker and stick it on the module?

Thanks

Comment: Of which module? (no link). Do you have a link or photo If it's an ESP2866 you MAY find the certification is worth the ink it's printed with.

Comment: @Kate Apparently :-). Nice reference. Many thanks. But the ESP-12 is one of several ESP modules available and, based on the Alibaba and other photos that I've peered at, the ESP8266 is used in a range of physical configurations - none of which are entitled to use the FCC ID that you have cited. |[AI-THINKER's page here](http://www.ai-thinker.com/) has apparently good related material (Translating from Chinese isneeded bt most of us.) The top "latest topic" queries the FCC ID status :-(. What & why I as yet know not.

Comment: With ID:[1](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-shipping-serial-uart-Ethernet-AP-Client-wifi-module-HLK-RM04-1-set-2db-wifi-antenna/211069_1246622440.html) [2](http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=39)
VARIES: [X](http://www.aliexpress.com/cheap/cheap-ethernet-wifi-module.html) 
WITHOUT: [A](http://www.electrodragon.com/product/wi04-wifi-module/#prettyPhoto[product-gallery]/0/) [B](http://www.smartarduino.com/uart-turn-wifi-module-serial-port-turn-ethernet-ethernet_p93896.html)

Comment: @JohnMunroe Question not fully understood. I think it highly likely your device is not formally certified but the product links above are interesting (perhaps :-) ) in that visually similar identical modules are sold with and without appended ID. I note that in at least some cases those without ID also were without brand (as yours is) and ID'd ones generally had a brand - usually to the left of "bgWiFin". Alas, in all cases but especially from China  you cannot trust any labelling without bulletproof "provenance", if then. Which is essentially what I said in my 1st comment above :-(.

Comment: ... IANAL nor more than very passingly experienced in FCC certification. The fcc.io link from Kate provides links to what the FCC want in the wy oflabelling. I think the RF module and the product need marking. || If you ordered a module shown in its ad with FCC id attached there is a moderate chance that it would arrive without one. Asking the seller is essential and even then it may fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my understanding.

Since it is a radio module, then it is definitely an intentional radiator and if they claim it has been FCC-certified it should have an FCC ID on each module.  You should contact the manufacturer and ask why it's not there.

[image]

If you incorporate the module into your own product, and the module already has an antenna (e.g. a "chip" antenna like the one in the picture) then you don't have to do anything more except provide the same FCC ID on the outside of your product, or ([as part of a recent rule change](http://www.multichannel.com/news/policy/fcc-loosens-device-labeling-restrictions/375863)) in an accessible menu if your product has a screen.  In any case, the FCC ID must also be included in a label on the outside of the package.

*However*, if the module has no antenna, and you connect it to one you made (e.g. PCB trace antenna) or bought, then guess what, you have to do the FCC testing all over again(!) which can many thousands of dollars.

It's been a few years since I was directly involved in a product like that (cell phone modem + PCB antenna), so I can't remember if you are supposed to include both the FCC ID for the modem and your own FCC ID, or just the latter.  I suspect it's both.

Comment: I can find their FCC ID on the FCC website. If it's not already printed on the module, could I print it out myself on a sticker and stick it on the module?

Comment: IANAL but it seems that's the best you can do.  Then you also need a label on the outside of your device (or on an LCD menu, as indicated above) plus on a label on the outside of your packaging.  Take the time to find the official FCC regulations on all of this and don't go by just what I say.

Comment: You can't print it out and stick it on the module, the FCC ID means the module has been through FCC testing and certification, and is product specific.

Answer (score 1):

Trust, but verify.
Or don't trust, but do verify.

You'll need to search the FCC database, or one of its many mirrors, for the actual certification documents.  Start here: https://www.fcc.gov/general/fcc-id-search-page and read up on Modular Approval here https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/comments/GetPublishedDocument.html?id=50&tn=916170 (FCC publication 996369 Section 15.212).

Now you'll see a grant, possibly an application for confidentiality, and some photos.  *Pay attention to the photos and match them up.*  Chances are your module is counterfeit, and all bets are off.

If you change the antenna at all, all bets are off and you must certify from scratch.  Europe does not recognize modular approval.