# FCC reguation for PCB in case of daughter board is FCC compliant

Tags: esp32, fcc

I am working on a project that uses the ESP32 WROOM module which is FCC compliant. I wonder if the FCC compliance gets void if new components are added to the module via a PCB. From my understanding, the major electromagnetic interference causing part of the board is already compliant. Does the entire board need to get FCC compliance confirmed again?

Thanks

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134556/clarification-about-fcc-exemption-for-subassemblies

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Mat